# Hibernate doesn't remove entities from the database if you change their identifiers. It just adds the new ones

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, wildfly

- Wildfly 21
- Hibernate 5.3.18.Final (JPA provider)

I stumbled in a very strange and nonintuitive behaviour in Hibernate.

**PhoneId**

```
@Embeddable
public class PhoneId
{
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private int personId;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_ID")
    private int phoneId;

    // Getters, setters...
}
```

**Phone**

```
@Entity
public class Phone
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private PhoneId id;

    private String number;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;

    // Getters, setters...
}
```

**Person**

```
@Entity
public class Person
{
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();

    // Getters, setters...
}
```

Now, suppose that I have these phones in the database associated with person with id `1`:

- PERSON_ID=1, PHONE_ID=1, NUMBER=phone1
- PERSON_ID=1, PHONE_ID=2, NUMBER=phone2

The I get a person:

```
Person person = em.find(Person.class, 1);
person.getPhones().size() // 2
```

and, working with it in detached mode, I change the two phone ids to 3 and 4, respectively. I also add a third phone with id 5 to this person. After that, I want to update the database with these changes with:

```
person.getPhones().size() // 3
Person newPerson = em.merge(person);
```

So, the problem is this:

After that, I would expect to see in the phones table in the database these records:

- PERSON_ID=1, PHONE_ID=3, NUMBER=phone1
- PERSON_ID=1, PHONE_ID=4, NUMBER=phone2
- PERSON_ID=1, PHONE_ID=5, NUMBER=phone3

But do you know what I see? I actually see this:

- PERSON_ID=1, PHONE_ID=1, NUMBER=phone1
- PERSON_ID=1, PHONE_ID=2, NUMBER=phone2
- PERSON_ID=1, PHONE_ID=3, NUMBER=phone1
- PERSON_ID=1, PHONE_ID=4, NUMBER=phone2
- PERSON_ID=1, PHONE_ID=5, NUMBER=phone3

So, when I saved the changes to the database I had only 3 phones in the collection and Hibernate didn't delete the phones that were in the database (their ids were no longer in the phone collection) and added to them in the database the phones with the new ids. What's happening here? What's the use of the `orphanRemoval` attribute if it doesn't remove the childs with ids that were no longer in the phones collection?

If I have only 3 phones in a collection I want to have only 3 phones in the database as well. Very fair. Why is Hibernate ignoring the phones that are already in the database and not deleting them? After all, the phones in the database have different ids than those in the collection.

This is completely nonintuitive and wrong in my opinion, but if I'm missing something or doing something wrong, I would like very much to know.

Comment: Phone Id is just that -- an ID, so new phones with a different ID are not the same as old phones with other IDs. If you keep the IDs the same, and just change (e.g.) the `number`, I think you'll see the behaviour you expect.

Comment: Sorry, don't agree. `orphanRemoval` is true. If I change the ids, why would I want other ids that are not in the collection to be in the database? After all, when the save operating is executing, Hibernate compares what's in the collection to what's in the database. Why does it let things in the database if they're not in the collection. Again, what's the use of `orphanRemoval`? PHONE_ID number 1 should not exist in the database if it's not in the phones collection anymore.

Comment: How is `mappedBy = "person"` working when Phone doesn't have a person field?

Comment: Phone does have a "person" field. It's just not show on the code here. It is the many to one side of the relationship, where the parent entity is set.

Comment: You're more likely to get a useful answer if you give people enough information to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I've just updated the question with the `person` property on the `Phone` entity.

Comment: Creating a duplicate of the entity when you change the ID is expected behavior. IDs are expected to be immutable. If you want the old record removed, you call `em.remove(Object)`. Also did you remember to override `equals` and `hashCode` in the `PhoneId` class? You're supposed to do that to ensure keys are compared properly.

Comment: @coladict Yes, I overrode `equals` and `hashCode` in the `PhoneId` class. `Phone` also has `equals` and `hashCode` overridden. _"Creating a duplicate of the entity when you change the ID is expected behavior"_; Can you point me to some specification or documentation to sustain that statement?

Comment: Let's continue the discussion on discourse: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-doesnt-remove-entities-from-the-database-if-you-change-their-identifiers-it-just-adds-the-new-ones/5534